# 5x5 binary grid with every 2x2 sub-grid occurring once

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you paint a $5 \times 5$ grid in two colors, such that each of the $2 \times 2$ possible sub-grids ($2^4 = 16$ combinations) occurs exactly once in the grid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is also possible to do this on a 4x4 torus grid (i.e. a 4x4 with wrap-around edges). This gives the solution:

> ```
> 0 0 0 1
> 0 0 1 0
> 1 0 1 1
> 0 1 1 1
> ```

As a 5x5 solution (just making the 5th row/column a copy of the 1st) this becomes

> ```
> 0 0 0 1 0
> 0 0 1 0 0
> 1 0 1 1 1
> 0 1 1 1 0
> 0 0 0 1 0
> ```

Of course

> you can cyclically rotate the rows and/or columns of the 4x4 grid to get equivalent solutions which will look different from each other when shown as a 5x5 grid.

Comment: Correct and well done! This is also known as De Bruijn Torus.

Comment: Here's an [SVG version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVkkFOwzAQRfc9xWgqJFhQ2w2qaBWnEgu2LKAHMImTWBg7it0k3B7HSQUSLFLJC3vm_e-R_qTH4VNDJ1unrOHINhRBmtwWylQcT2_P948IzgtTCG2N5GgsHrNV6roKgtI4jrX3zYGQvu83fbKxbUW2lFISCFzBBB0GrczHfyjb7_ckdke4U7J_sgNHChTYLhwMfxWydFnopo3wXrYGVMHxXdsBYa6cjPJhkrOT7WsjcvliTk6OhgC9KnzN8QGhlqqq_XjNYietoFRac1yXpZhrodrK3EMYIUH4CoPgxYH9ODAkf_BtxNlSnEZ8e537Yjy5DmcRT64bZjGeLMBTUsWEyRxoSJ1MsU82FymlN7_U8TVnKEQZzGApf2717XrcobtJNa5r9g1vXdj-&lang=html) of the torus pattern, repeated.

Comment: Dmitry: a tessellation with a [cross of St Brigid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigid%27s_cross) design.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is:

> **Yes**, with one possible solution being the following:
>
> ```
> 0 0 1 1 0
> 0 0 1 1 0
> 1 0 0 1 1
> 0 0 1 1 0
> 1 1 0 0 1
> ```

If we list out all the possible subgrids in the 4×4 layout, it looks like this:

> ```
> 0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0
> 0 0   0 1   1 0   1 1
>
> 0 1   0 1   0 1   0 1
> 0 0   0 1   1 0   1 1
>
> 1 0   1 0   1 0   1 0
> 0 0   0 1   1 0   1 1
>
> 1 1   1 1   1 1   1 1
> 0 0   0 1   1 0   1 1
> ```

Then each tile goes to the corresponding row number as shown below:

> ```
> 1 3 2 4
> 2 1 4 3
> 3 4 1 2
> 4 2 3 1
> ```

which is a

> Latin square.

Comment: Can you explain more the connection between the second and the third spoiler box?

Comment: @justhalf The first row in the main answer contains four tiles (in the second box) labeled 1 (in the third box), the second row contains those labeled 2, and so on.

Comment: Ah, I see. But what about the order within each row? Seems quite arbitrary to me. It's not column-wise, and it's not by traversing the 4x4 grid in order. So seems like this is not a path to the solution, but just a nice observable properties of which tiles went where in a solution you found previously (perhaps via trial and error)?

Comment: @justhalf I just went row-by-row, spending four tiles at once. I randomly picked the tiles that would go to the first row (those just looked nice), and looking at the diagonal crossed out I immediately thought "oh, looks like a Latin square pattern might work", and it simply did (I didn't have to backtrack at all). The column order in each row happens to be some cyclic shift of `1 2 4 3`.

Comment: Correct answer. I accepted Jaap's solution for the extra torus connection.

Comment: Does one find a solution to this problem using brute force/ trial and error or is there some logical path to get to the solution ?